# How to fight and control equipped motorcycle driver

Tags: self-defense

Unfortunately, in some situations motorcycle drivers that are equipped with helmets, boots and suits attack. Is there a way to fight back and control them with inability to attack their face, legs and upper body?

Comment: -1. This is prime example of why I want to [burninate the `self defence` tag](http://meta.martialarts.stackexchange.com/q/407/82). It is a hypothetical situation. It covers so much ground that the only possible answer is "it depends". It has no relation to any martial art whatsoever.

Comment: I would think wearing a motorcycle helmet would be a disadvantage because of weight, blind spots, and possibly the chance of it being spun around (depending on the fit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are certain considerations you must take into account with this type of opponent.

### The head

They have a helmet on, so regular boxing style techniques are going to have less or nil effect. Helmets are specifically designed to spread impact so you shouldn't attempt a king hit on the helmet - you will break your hand.
You could however apply mechanics. A helmet protects the skull (and maybe face) but it doesn't protect or enhance the neck and shoulder musculature. You can use this fact to exert some mechanical theory: the opponent will still be prone to head rotational and snapping movements. So an uppercut at a 45° angle through the chin area should still produce a knockout.

### Boots

Boots protect the feet nicely, so there's no point attacking them. While the ankle area will still be a weak area it is augmented by the boot so will still be a hard target.

### Legs

Even if padded pants are being worn the opponent will still be prone to thigh attacks and upper calf attacks (depending on the height of the boots). Some pants will have knee protection but this will be more for protecting the patella; the knee will still be vulnerable to sideways forces.

### Jackets/gloves

Jackets and gloves will make it harder to exploit wrist and elbow locks and leverage that requires pinpoint control. Joints still move the same way they always do, it's just harder - for example I wouldn't attempt a koto gaeshi, but I would attempt an arm bar. This also don't stop you from using brute force against a wide area, i.e. power punches or kicks to the rib area.

### Summary

The opponent will be harder to attack, but you simply need to change your approach. Use brute force techniques on exposed areas (thighs, side of knee, ribs, neck). Use techniques that leverage mechanical weaknesses in the musculoskeletal structure. Remember that due to the bulk of the clothing the opponent will be slower, so use this to your advantage. Don't forget other basics like using other opponents and/or objects like lampposts to hinder incoming attacks.

Answer (score 4):

A motorcycle driver in protective gear is similar to an armored opponent. Striking the opponent may not be effective, but you can still use grappling techniques. This striking constraint makes the situation like that in wrestling, judo, or jujutsu; except you are constrained by circumstances and not competition rules. You can still throw them, use other takedowns, apply joint locks, sweep legs, and so forth.